# How find box arests based only in volume

Tags: geometry, polynomials, interpolation

I'm trying to figure how I can find the dimensions of a box based only on the volume. Lets imagine I have a box with:

**height: 13 cm**
**width: 6 cm**
**lenght: 8 cm**

Using the volume formula ($v=l*h*w$) I get 624 $cm^3$ as volume.
However what I want is the contrary, I have the volume and I want find the edges. I've made the following suppositions:

**height: x**
**width: x+n**
**length: x+k**

$$v=x^3+x^2(n+k)+xkn$$

so if my volume is 624 $cm^3$, how can I solve this?

$$x3+x2(n+k)+xkn=624$$

Comment: That equation has infinitely many solutions if you do not specify some constraints on $n$,$k$ or $x$

Comment: If we assume that all 3 dimensions are integers, we could have finite set of solutions.  For example, for a box of volume 624, its dimensions could be 156x2x2, 78x4x2, 39x4x4, 16x13x3, 13x8x6,.....

Comment: @fang is there a way I can find these solutions or only try and error?

Comment: There is a systematic way to find these solutions. The first is to do "prime factorization" against the integer (i.e., turning 624 into 2^4*3*13). The rest would be to find combination of these prime factors to form your solution.